# deleting errors from printer queue and restarting Spooler service

Tags: powershell

am trying to delete errors in the printer queue that come in <1 minute and restart the service.

We have multiple printers on a server just trying to delete error messages on printer that have error in the queue and restart the service. I am a beginner at PowerShell

Here is what I have so far:

$Computername = Read-Host -Prompt 'In put computer Name'

$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computername

Invoke-Command -Session $Session {(Remove-Item C:\backup -force)}